# How does the integral $\int y''\cdot y'\text{ d}x$ work in the context of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958730/how-can-i-solve-the-differential-equation-y-y-ay) question, the accepted answer starts off solving the diffeq $(y'/y)'=-ay$ by substituting $u = \log y$ to get $u'' = -a e^{u}$ and then multiplying both sides with $u'$ and integrating both sides to get $$\frac{(u')^{2}}{2} = -a e^{u} + \frac{c_{1}}{2}$$
I am baffled at how to get $$\int u'' \cdot u' \text{ d}x=\frac{(u')^{2}}{2}$$
through the context of differentials. Typically, I can understand integrating say $u'(x)$ through differentials, where we have
$$\int \frac{du}{dx}\text{ d}x = \int \text{ d}u = u+C$$
How do I get the same thing for integrating $u'' u'$?

Obviously, I can see this through the chain rule where $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac12 y'^2\right] = \frac12\cdot 2y'\cdot y'' = y'' y'$$
but I cannot reason how how the integral would work
$$\int \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}\text{ d}x = \int \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \text{ d}u?????$$

Help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Let $y = u'$ and rinse repeat the same logic above..

Comment: To answer the question in the title: $[(y’)^2]’=2y’y”\Rightarrow \int{y’y”dx}=\frac 12(y’)^2+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=y'$ ; thus  $\hspace{3pt} dz/dx=y''$, that is, by law of substitution, $dz = y''dx$

Then,
$I = \int y'' y' dx = \int y' (y'' dx) = \int z dz = z^2/2 + c= (y')^2/2+c$

Answer (score 1):

> I can understand integrating say $u′(x)$ through differentials, where we have
> $$ \int \dfrac {du}{dx} dx=\int  du=u+C$$

You can use the same trick:
$$\int u'' \cdot u' \text{ d}x=\int u'  \dfrac {du'}{dx}\text{ d}x=\int u' \text{ d}u'=\frac{(u')^{2}}{2}+C$$